# Is my power supply design safe and effective?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, tp4056

I'm making power supplies for RC cars. I need to be sure that they are safe and that I'm getting enough current to run everything on the car.
I am planning on using 3 LM2596 Buck converters:

- @10V to power 2 dual h-bridges and 4 tt motors
- @5V to power 40 WS2812B LED String
- @5V to power ESP32-CAM on WiFi and an Arduino Uno

I added the relay to disable all of the car's power while it's charging.

- Do I have this wired correctly?
- Do I need to join the grounds from the output and input sides of the charger? I suspect the answer is no.
- Is this safe for a toy for my kid?
- Does the TP4056 prevent against back-charging or do I need diodes on the parallel output? Again, I suspect I'm fine without them.
- Should I add a 5 minute timer to the relay to allow the batteries to settle before they are used?
- Am I missing any necessary discrete components?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you planning to get 5 and 10V from 3.7V using step-down regulators like LM2596?

Comment: @Unimportant See, I'm glad I asked. Apparently, I made a mistake in my component selection. I thought the LM2596 was a buck and a boost. Should I just look for a boost converter instead?

Comment: 1) The TP4056 has only an input (5 V for charging) and the +/- battery connections. Your "TP4056" has 6 connections, does it include battery protection? 2) You seem to be connecting the (battery) outputs of the TP4056 modules in parallel. **That is really asking for trouble.** Never connect batteries in parallel as large currents can start to flow. 3) **No** this is not a safe circuit to use in a toy. 4) I advice you to forget about using multiple batteries and multiple TP4056, instead get **one** battery pack that can deliver the current you need.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I added a picture of the TP4056 that I have on hand. It does have 6 pins. There are many applications for the use of parallel batteries in vehicles, what am I missing that makes them safe and mine not? Why is the entire thing not safe, a simple declaration does not help me understand the issue.

Comment: The cells themselves are connected in parallel in such cases, making absolutely sure they are completely balanced at the moment they are placed in parallel. A tiny diffirence in voltage between cells when they are placed in parallel can result in huge currents otherwise. Once a group of cells is in parallel this battery is then charged/discharged as a whole, using only a single charger.

Comment: A TP4056 is an IC.  You have a module that includes a TP4056 - the distinction can be important.

Comment: *Why is the entire thing not safe* How about: "Never connect batteries in parallel as large currents can start to flow." *But they're not in parallel" No but Yes, between the output +/- and the battery connection on that "TP4056" module there's a battery protection circuit. This connects the battery **directly** to the out +/- (unless there is a fault). You're making up your own circuit and it has fatal flaws. It goes too far to fully explain what you did wrong so just take our word for it. I suggest you educate yourself on how to deal with Lithium batteries and circuits that use them.

Answer (score 2):

- Need to connect grounds on output - No, because you would short out the charger and defeat the battery protection of charger modules. You have also paralleled the cells, but since you talk about buck converters, you can't parallel the cells. You need the cells in series.
- Safe for kids - Unlikely, I would not trust self-made devices made from random ebay/amazon modules and lithium batteries to not explode in the hands of kids
- Wired correctly - No, as I said, the cells can't work in parallel, if you intend to use a buck converter.

Comment: I get the buck converter part. I mentioned in a comment response that I mistakenly selected the buck converter when I should have selected a boost converter. With a boost converter is the parallel wiring correct? I went with parallel output to eliminate the need to balance the cells before putting them in serial on a BMS.

Comment: You still need to balance the cells extremely well before connecting them in parallel. But what's the point in having four charger modules with paralleled output? Paralleling batteries also means higher battery currents for same power.